# shell script - input parameters to second level script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I am creating a shell script, which executes another shell script.

The second script needs some parameters and I want to pass them without having to wait the prompt.

So it is something like this:

```
SECOND_SCRIPT=script_2.sh
$SECOND_SCRIPT

#Do something to pass parameters to SECOND_SCRIPT

#Continue normal script.
```

At the point where the `$SECOND_SCRIPT` is executed, it shows the `SECOND_SCRIPT` menu, and I have to input some parameters. I want to pass them inside the `FIRST_SCRIPT`.

Comment: Parameters are the arguments on the command line, sounds like you mean input.

Comment: Either pass them as commandline arguments (`myScript2.sh 1 2 3`) or pipe them in (`echo "1 2 3" | myScript2.sh`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a here-doc:

```
$SECOND_SCRIPT <<EOF
input1
input2
...
EOF
```